# Spring OAuth2 login with Google and APIs access

Tags: spring-boot, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to implement Google login and use the Google Calendar API.

First of all I configured `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` with the following properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-name-attribute=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile,openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Then I read I could inject an instance of the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` in my controller in order to generate API credencials, so I did:

```java
@PostMapping("/meetings")
public String scheduleGoogleMeeting(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("google") OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2Client) {
```

And got my credentials like this:

```java
private Calendar getCalendar(OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

  Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod());
  credential.setAccessToken(client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());

  // the refresh_token is always null!
  //credential.setRefreshToken(client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());

  return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                     .setApplicationName("My App")
                     .build();
}
```

Everything works fine when I login with my Google Account, grant the required permissions and head directly to my `scheduleGoogleMeeting`. But if the token expires then I'm asked to grant permissions again and then I'm redirected to:

http://localhost:8080/authorize/oauth2/code/google?state=...

But it returns a **404 Not Found**.

This is my security configuration so far:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.sessionManagement()
  // more form login config
  .and()
  .oauth2Login().loginPage("/signin")
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oAuth2UserDetailsService);
```

Any ideas on how can I get this authorization endpoint working?

Comment: any chance you can add authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent") should have something to do with the authorizationendpoint.   Im trying to remember how to fix this its been a while.

Comment: thanks but there are no methods to change the `authorizationUri` (if any), did you manage to the login and api access working?